# The eigenvalue and expression in characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The characteristic polynimial of a matrix T looks like $(x-\lambda_1)^{k_1}...(x-\lambda_n)^{k_n}$. I'm confused about the $\lambda$s in the polynomial. Do they have to be the eigenvalue of the operator T?.

Also, If the vector space is $V$ and there is an operator $T: V\rightarrow V$, and there are two kinds of basis vectors of $V$. Suppose the basis for $V$ is $(v_1,...v_m,u_1,...,u_n)$. Basis vector v has property $(T-1)v_i=0$.

On the other hand, basis vector u has property $T^2u=u$, i.e.$(T^2-1)u=0$ that is $(T-1)(T+1)u=0$, and $(T-1)u\neq0$ and $(T+1)u\neq0$. Then can I conclude that the minimal polynomial of this matrix is $(T-1)(T+1)$? However, -1 is not the eigenvalue of T. This is what confuses me.

---

Edit: a more detailed description of vector space $V$

Let vector space $V=\mathbb R^2 \otimes \mathbb R^2$ and suppose $\mathbb R^2$ has basis $(e_1,e_2)$. Thus, the basis for $V=\mathbb R^2 \otimes \mathbb R^2$  will be ($e_1\otimes e_1$,$e_1\otimes e_2$,$e_2\otimes e_1$,$e_2\otimes e_2$).

Then the operator $T$ is defined as $Tv \otimes u=u\otimes v$. Then for $e_1\otimes e_1$ and $e_2\otimes e_2$, they are two eigenvectors of T with eigenvalue 1. For the $e_1\otimes e_2$ and $e_2\otimes e_1$.

$T^2 e_2\otimes e_1=e_2\otimes e_1$ i.e. $(T^2-1)e_2\otimes e_1=0$

This also implies that $(T+1)(T-1)e_2\otimes e_1=0$.However, $(T+1)e_2\otimes e_1\neq0$ and$(T-1)e_2\otimes e_1\neq 0$,but the polynomial operator $(T+1)(T-1)$ indeed is a zero operator for vector space $V$, and it is even the minimal polynomial. Then can -1 be the eigenvalue of T?

Comment: Yes, the roots of the characteristic polynomial are exactly the eigenvalues. If $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$, then the minimal polynomial won't have a factor $x+1$.

Comment: By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, the characteristic polynomial is a polynomial that has appearance p(x)=$(x-\lambda_1)^{k_1}...(x-\lambda_n)^{k_n}$ and each root of this polynomial should be the eigenvalue of the operator.  Also p(T)=$(T-\lambda_1)^{k_1}...(T-\lambda_n)^{k_n}$ should be a zero operator on $V$. In the example, $(T-1)(T+1)$ is indeed a zero polynomial with the least degree on vector space $V$, but since $-1$ is not the eigenvalue of operator T,  $(T-1)(T+1)$ won't be the minimal polynomial?

Comment: I think, at least as it's written, we don't have enough information on $T$, and either $T$ has eigenvalue $-1$ (e.g. $T(u_i)=-u_i$ for some (or all) $i$), or $T={\rm id}$.

Comment: I edit the question a little bit and come up with an example. I hope it will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roots of both the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial are exactly the eigenvalues.

In your case, your argument is fine, and $-1$ will indeed be an eigenvalue with eigenvector $e_1\otimes e_2\,-\,e_2\otimes e_1$.

Comment: Then in the vector space, $V\otimes V$ the minimal polynomial will be $(T-1)(T+1)$ right?. And characteristic polynomial will be $(T-1)^{n}(T+1)^{n^2-n}$ right?

Comment: Yes, the minimal polynomial is correct. We paired up the $2\cdot(n\binom 2)$ elements $e_i\otimes e_j$ with $i\ne j$. One half of it has eigenvalue $-1$, the other half $+1$. It's going to be $(x+1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}2}(x-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}2}$.

Comment: Yes, I find the characteristic polynomial was wrong, but it takes me a quite long time since the way I found that just by finding $e_1\otimes e_2+e_2\otimes e_1$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue 1 and $e_1\otimes e_2-e_2\otimes e_1$ is the eigenvector of eigenvalue -1 by a lot of computations. Is there some method to find this more quickly?